# C - struct as a return value does not fit

Tags: c, struct, return-value

when I compile my programm I get an error telling me:
"incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct timeStamp *' from type 'struct timeStamp'"

I don't have any clue what's wrong...
Maybe it's a problem with the struct in struct?

Very thankful for your help!
THX - kind regards!

Here's my crap code...

struct declaration:

```
struct timeStamp {
   int year;
   int mon;
   int day;
   int hour;
   int min;
};

struct weatherData {
   float temp;
   float hum;
   int lum;
   int wind;
   struct timeStamp *weatherStamp;
   struct weatherData *pN;
};
```

the function timeManipulate that should return a struct:

```
struct timeStamp timeManipulate(struct tm *timeinfo) {
    timeinfo->tm_min -= 10;
    mktime(timeinfo);

    struct timeStamp *tS = NULL;
    tS = (struct timeStamp*)malloc(sizeof(struct timeStamp));
    if (tS==NULL)
        perror("Allocation Error");

    tS->year = (timeinfo->tm_year)+1900;
    tS->mon = (timeinfo->tm_mon)+1;
    tS->day = timeinfo->tm_mday;
    tS->hour = timeinfo->tm_hour;
    tS->min = timeinfo->tm_min;
    return *tS;
};
```

in main() I want to assign the struct returned by "timeManipulate" to the other structure:

```
struct weatherData *pNew = NULL;
pNew->weatherStamp = timeManipulate(timeinfo);
```

Comment: Another solution would be to have `weatherData` contain `struct timeStamp weatherStamp;`, and stop using `malloc`.  I don't see what benefit there is to offloading part of your data to `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should return a pointer

```
struct timeStamp *timeManipulate(struct tm *timeinfo)
/*               ^ make the function return a struct tiemStamp pointer */
```

and the return value should be

```
return tS;
```

Also, your

```
if (ts == NULL)
    perror("Allocation Error");
```

will still dereference the `NULL` pointer, it should be something like

```
if (ts == NULL)
{
    perror("Allocation Error");
    return NULL;
}
```

and this will not work of course

```
struct weatherData *pNew = NULL;
pNew->weatherStamp = timeManipulate(timeinfo);
```

you must allocate space for `pNew` too.

Finally don't cast the result of `malloc()` it's not needed.